# Cancel running build with Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm using the Quasar Framework to develop a frontend application.

I forgot to disable the Webpack Bundle Analyzer and it is now waiting for a CTRL+C signal, preventing the Heroku build to finish.

Using `heroku ps`, there is no process associated to the build that I can kill with `heroku ps:kill`.

Is there any way to cancel a build ? Or do I have to delete the app and recreate it again ?